# SQL HELP - Latest date and unique by user

Tags: aggregate, distinct

```
NAME + LAST_LOGIN_DATE_TIME 
=============================
Anna     12-DEC-14
Micky    24-JAN-15
Anna     31-JAN-15
Micky    09-FEB-15
Micky    02-MAR-15
```

I am looking to pull up unique name's with the latest date logged on date.
I would like the result to return:

```
Anna     31-JAN-15
Micky    02-MAR-15
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assuming that date column is of a proper type (date, datetime, timestamp), then `SELECT name, MAX(last_login_date_time) FROM  ... GROUP BY name;` should work.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

You can simple use MAX function like this:

```
select NAME , max(LAST_LOGIN_DATE_TIME )
from table_name
group by NAME;
```

Or you can also use OREDER BY, like this :

```
select NAME, LAST_LOGIN_DATE_TIME 
from table_name t
where LAST_LOGIN_DATE_TIME in (select LAST_LOGIN_DATE_TIME 
from table_name i  where i.NAME = t.NAME order by LAST_LOGIN_DATE_TIME desc limit 1) ;
```